# Why the dialog is rendering many times?

Tags: reactjs, antd

i would like to show a confirmation dialog if a condicion is not correct

in the function to submit the form, i have this condition to show the warnign dialog, this condition `if (sections.length && !sections[0].id) {`

```
const [showConfirmationDialog, setShowConfirmationDialog] = useState(false)

  const handleSubmitForm = (values) => {
    ...
    if (sections.length && !sections[0].id) {
      setShowConfirmationDialog(true)
    }
    ...


const handleConfirm =()=> confirm({
      title: 'Do you want to delete these items?',
      content: 'When clicked the OK button, this dialog will be closed after 1 second',
      async onOk() { },
      onCancel() { },
    })

  return (
    <>
      <Form
        autoComplete="off"
        form={form}
        layout="vertical"
        name="section-form"
        onFinish={handleSubmitForm}
        ...
        {showConfirmationDialog  && handleConfirm() }
```

its rendering many times and i am getting this error:

Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {destroy, update}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the returned value from the confirm function is not a React Component, you should call the confirm function directly not as a component.

You can head to the link https://ant.design/components/modal#modal-demo-hooks to get the examples.

Comment: only should it work with a button?

Comment: No, the point is not about the trigger element. Imagine there is an element in the body, you can toggle the element‘s visibility by setting the display style value. The confirm function does the same things as this, so you don’t need to use it as a component.